# Regex to find mismatched moustache notation finds fullmatch on correct occurances

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate some simple mustache notation where `{{foo}}` is correct and `{bar}}` or `{{taz}` is incorrect.

These are the regex I've tried so far.

/{{.*?}}/g for correct occurrances

`/(^|[^{]){.*?}}/g` and `/{{.*?}([^}]|$)/g` for incorrect occurances

The problem is that incorrect regex match correct occurance.

My code on js

```
function getTokenMatches(text) {
  let tokenMatches = [];
  const correctTokenMatches = text.match(/{{.*?}}/g);
  if (correctTokenMatches) {
    tokenMatches.push(...correctTokenMatches);
  }
  const openLeftTokenMatches = text.match(/[^{]{.*?}}/g);
  if (openLeftTokenMatches) {
    tokenMatches.push(...openLeftTokenMatches);
  }
  const openRightTokenMatches = text.match(/{{.*?}[^}]/g);
  if (openRightTokenMatches) {
    tokenMatches.push(...openRightTokenMatches);
  }
  tokenMatches = tokenMatches.map(token => {
    let regex = new RegExp(/{{.*?}[^}]/g);
    if (regex.test(token)) {
      token = `${token}}`;
    }
    regex = new RegExp(/[^{]{{.*?}/g);
    if (regex.test(token)) {
      token = `{${token}`;
    }
    return token;
  });
  return tokenMatches;
}
```

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/hD9oI7/4

Comment: what if you write in quotes RegExp `("/{{.*?}[^}]/g")` ?

Comment: How about using a [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) inside the braces together with a negative lookahead after the closing `}` like in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD9oI7/5).

Comment: Oh! cool @bobblebubble I'm gonna try that :)

Comment: @Pikk you don't need to add quotes when you instantiate a regex

Comment: what about ```{{ fo{o }}``` or  ```{{ fo{{bar}}o }}```  ?

Comment: @user753642 those are cases that are assummed to be failing

Comment: @bobblebubble your proposal works on negative lookahead but when I try to use negative lookbehind it takes correct matches as incorrect, like this [This demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD9oI7/6)

Comment: @DavidMarín I think in such cases it's the most simple, to [match what you don't want, but capture what you need](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). So, if I just needed to identify those and inside the `{{...}}` there is no braces allowed, see [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hD9oI7/7). The lookbehind you mentioned won't work in most browsers JS. You'd need to do it without lookbehind `(?:^|[^{]){`... but keep the lookahead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll take a look at that

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/hD9oI7/8

Comment: @DavidMarín [Here is a JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0o6wLht/) with what I meant. But georg's idea is great already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try removing "good" patterns first, and then match `{+ ... }+` to find "bad" ones:

```js
markup = `
    {{ this }} is {{ fine }} and so is {{ that }}
    {this one}} is no good, and so is {{{{this one}
    this is {{{more {{complicated}} ?? }
`

good = []
bad = []

m = markup
m = m.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, m => good.push(m))
m = m.replace(/{+[^{}]+}+/g, m => bad.push(m))

console.log(good)
console.log(bad)
```

Depending on whether `{{{ this }}` should be "good" or "bad", you can refine the "good" pattern to

```
/[^{]{{[^{}]+}}[^}]/g
```

Comment: I think that @David Martin specified that ```{{ fo{{bar}} o}}``` is invalid. Most probably ```{{{more {{complicated}} ?? }``` should make an invalid ```{{{```  followed by valid ```{{complicated}} ```. The capture the good first would thus be invalid for ```{{ foo {{ bar }} }}``` as it should invalidate ```{{ foo {```, and ```{ bar }}``` instead of accepting ```bar```

Comment: @user753642: yes, speaking generally, regexes are not good with nesting, to handle all cases reliably they might want to use a grammar-driven parser.

Comment: Thanks @georg your answers were really helpful, I ended up using some sort of validation like this one :)